# how to add line height in my FPDF file using PHP

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I have a small problem in the following code

```
<?php
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');

//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->AddPage();

//set font to arial, bold, 14pt
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);

//Cell(width , height , text , border , end line , [align] )

$pdf->Cell(200  ,5,'National Remote Sensing Center',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(50  ,5,'Flight REquisition Form',1,1,'C');
```

I have a title and a sub title . But i need some line height between them. can anyone tell the code for line height adjustment?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into a docs or examples.

Comment: @panther - isn't the other post for multicell() vs cell() here? seems slightly different, or is the behavior the same in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use the second paramter of the Cell() method... **height?**

```
Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
```

> **h**
>
> Cell height. Default value: 0.

from http://www.fpdf.org/ > Manual > Cell()

Comment: sorry.. but thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: so what happens? have you found a solution?

Comment: yeah! i have to just add an empty cell.. It works alright!